# Posting from PHP to PHP

Tags: php, post

I am working on creating a system which is secured by passing tokens from page to page to verify the validity of requests.  The token is to be generated on the login page (as it only needs to be generated once) and then passed through to the main page.  However, there is an intermediate PHP script which is being run to log the user in, and I am not sure how to take the posted token and pass it on to the main page.

In short, I need to post the token from the login page to the intermediary script, and then from the script to the main page, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further consideration, it looks like I was making things much more complicated than they needed to be.  Thank you all for your help, but the solution seems to be that I should be a bit more intelligent.

Comment: Would you care to share with us what your eventual solution was?

Comment: I realized that I didn't need to create the variable where I was creating it, and could instead create it on the other side of the PHP script.  Rather than solving the problem, I circumvented it.

Sorry if that's not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 pages are on the same host, use a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: I'm specifically avoiding any such variables, as I want to ensure that the user's request is part of a chain starting from the beginning of their session.  The token passed by posting will be compared to a session variable; if the two are different, it is assumed that the request is invalid.  As such, I need to pass through a copy of the token as a posted variable.

Comment: What is the purpose of said functionality, maybe then i can understand what you are describing here. Besides.. you cannot force the client to post ANYTHING without client side scripting, which can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a cookie/session instead:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['token'] = 'yourTokenHere'
```

See [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Client side cookies:

```
<?php
setcookie("token", $myToken);
?>
```

The biggest fault with this method is that it absolutely requires the user to have cookies enabled on their browser. In highly secure situations a user may not have cookies enabled so this method wouldn't work for them.

### Use `$_SESSION` global variable:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['token'] = $myToken;
?>
```

As previous variant, it requires cookies to be enabled.

### Add `$_GET` parameter to URI string:

```
http://example.com?token=f4FArqk53Gwr4fESC73FedG48Trd3YEj
```

The biggest fault of this method is that your `URI` string will look very complex.

Also state information will be lost if user will manually modify `URI`.

### Or pass everything in Hidden form fields:

Unfortunately it requires you to submit a form on every page.

You can do it with `jQuery`.

---

Some examples are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145945/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041600-2.shtml).

Comment: Can you make those headers a bit bigger and bolder, please. Having trouble reading them :P

Comment: @navnav That is the default Stack Overflow markup, so I can't do anything with it, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a long time ago:

```
function postheader($url, $server, $cookies, $daten)
{   
    $temp=array();
    $out = "POST ".$url." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: ".$server."\r\n";
    if(count($cookies)>0)
    {
        $out .= "Cookie: ";
        foreach($cookies as $name=>$value)
        {
            $temp[] = $name."=".$value;
        }
        $out .= implode("; ",$temp);
        $out .= "\r\n";
    }
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $temp=array();
    foreach($daten as $key=>$data)
    {
        $temp[] = $key."=".urlencode($data);
    }
    $temp=implode("&",$temp);
    $out .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($temp)."\r\n";
    $out .= "\r\n";
    $out .= $temp."\r\n";

    return $out;
}


$fp = fsockopen($server, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp)
   die( "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n");

$out=postheader($url, $server, $cookies, $daten);
//echo $out;

fwrite($fp, $out);
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $string.= fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
```

$daten should be a one dimensional associative array containing the data you want to send via the post request. For cookies, just add an empty array.

$server is the host address, and $url is only the address on the server, e.g.

```
$server="stackoverflow.com";
$url="/post.php";
```

$string will contain the whole response including the headers. If you don't want them, do a substring from the first "\r\n\r\n" occurence.